# how to fix invalid factories after rails 5 update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm trying to update a rails 4.1.1 app to 5.  When I try to run my specs I am getting the following errors and I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
An error occurred in a `before(:suite)` hook.
Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.lint

FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError:
  The following factories are invalid:

  * activity - undefined method `alias_hostname' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fdf43741ec0> (NoMethodError)
  * ownership_transfer - undefined method `alias_hostname' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fdf43741ec0> (NoMethodError)
  * user - undefined method `alias_hostname' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fdf43741ec0> (NoMethodError)
  * salesperson - undefined method `alias_hostname' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fdf43741ec0> (NoMethodError)
  * admin - undefined method `alias_hostname' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fdf43741ec0> (NoMethodError)
# /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/linter.rb:12:in `lint!'
# /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl.rb:67:in `lint'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Line 47 of my rails_helper is FactoryGirl.lint

Comment: What is `alias_hostname`? What does the offending factory code look like?

Comment: Looks like that was a value another dev had put into a production config file but wasn't in the test config file.  I added it there and it looks like I can move on.  Thanks.

Comment: I was having same error:

➜  conekta git:(master) ✗ rspec  

Randomized with seed 42117

An error occurred in a `before(:suite)` hook.
Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.lint

FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError:
  The following factories are invalid:

  * account - unknown keyword: public_key (ArgumentError)
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'


Finished in 0.06539 seconds (files took 2.36 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 42117

I just fix my class, there was something wrong with a private method, pass your code